# How to replace a segment of Text that is dynamic in different files?

Tags: python, string, dynamic, replace

Here is my Python Code :

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
filedata = file.read()

filedata = filedata.replace("""section a {
sub1{ Dynamic Content 1}   
sub2{ Dynamic Content 2}      
sub3{ Dynamic Content 3}

 };""", """section a {
 sub1{ Dynamic Content 1}   
 sub2{ This is replacement text }     
 sub3{ Dynamic Content 3} 
 };""")

with open('input.txt', 'w') as file:
file.write(filedata)
```

input.txt file :

```
section a {
sub1{ Dynamic Content 1}  
sub2{ Dynamic Content 2}      
sub3{ Dynamic Content 3}

};


section b {
sub1{ Dynamic Content 4}   
sub2{ Dynamic Content 5}
sub3{ Dynamic Content 6}

};
```

I have a few more files like `input.txt` in the same format. i.e.

1. Section a and section b are unique, static and non-repetitive in a given file.
2. `sub1`,`sub2`,`sub3` are static and repetitive in a given file.
3. content in `sub1`,`sub2`,`sub3` varies with different `input.txt` files.

**I would like to replace the content in section a-sub2  with `"This is replacement text"` regardless of the dynamic content.**

The script above works if I know the dynamic content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import re

def replaceText():
    with open('input.txt') as file:
        filedata=file.read()
        newText=re.sub(r'(section a.*?sub2)({.*?})', r'\1{This is replacement text}', filedata, flags=re.DOTALL)
    with open('input.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(newText)

replaceText()
```